# How to prevent user from executing javascript code from console?

Tags: javascript, console, execution

I am storing some sensitive data on javascript side. How can I prevent user from tampering these data. I can not do this on server side with ajax or anything else, as smoothness of the animation concerned.

Comment: is it possible anyway to control other's browser???

Comment: How do you cram so much "wrong" into so such a short sentence...?  Don't store sensitive data client-side - it's that simple!

Comment: Store "sensitive data" on javascript side? IMO both concepts together on a sentence are wrong.

Comment: @Emissary: Seems like you've edited the comment - it looked like you were critiquing the grammer.

Answer (score 2):

Make your JavaScript inaccessible to someone using function scope etc. This isn't perfect but it can certainly make things a lot harder. For example, if you define:

```
var f = function() { return "test"; }
f();
```

Then it's easy to call `window.f()`

If instead you define as a self invoking function then you've just made it much more difficult for someone to call:

```
(function() { 
return test;
})();
```

This principle can then be extended - any variables defined within the function, will only have scope within it making it very difficult (but probably not impossible) to get hold of them.